# Remove the Parent Element without removing the childs-DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

Have to convert my raw XML to desired XML which will be understood by my application.

Using DOM(take it as a restriction) and unfortunately i can only use Java,DOM.Have tried XSLT but unfortunately not allowed to use it.

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><ns0:EMessage xmlns:ns0="http://www.abc/Something">
        <ns0:Header>
        <ns0:Snumber>1613</ns0:Snumber>
        </ns0:Header>
        <ns0:Name>SomeEvent</ns0:Name>
        <ns0:NameSpace>http://www.abc/Something.xsd</ns0:NameSpace>
        <ns0:Id>3</ns0:Id>
        <ns0:myProperty>
          <ns0:Name>ExtId</ns0:Name>
          <ns0:Value>TEST_ID_12</ns0:Value>
        </ns0:myProperty>
        <ns0:myProperty>
          <ns0:Name>CVersion</ns0:Name>
          <ns0:Value>0</ns0:Value>
        </ns0:myProperty>
        </ns0:EMessage>
```

Till now with my trials and google i have reached here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><ns0:EMessage xmlns:ns0="http://www.abc/Something">
<ns0:Header>
<ns0:Snumber>1613</ns0:Snumber>
</ns0:Header>
<ns0:Name>SomeEvent</ns0:Name>
<ns0:NameSpace>http://www.abc/Something.xsd</ns0:NameSpace>
<ns0:Id>3</ns0:Id>
<ns0:eventProperty>
    <ExtId>TEST_ID_12</ExtId>
  </ns0:eventProperty>
  <ns0:eventProperty>
    <CVersion>0</CVersion>
  </ns0:eventProperty>
</ns0:EMessage>
```

In my above code i have taken root as `<ns0:EMessage>` element and taken all the nodes as list node.Converted the element to desired form by creating a new element with values pulled from the input raw XML.But as i have taken `</ns0:eventProperty>` as the parent.I do not need this element,So basically i need to remove this parent node and the child to this parent should become the immideate child of `<ns0:EMessage>`.I do not need to touch other elements.

**Desired OUTPUT**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><ns0:EMessage xmlns:ns0="http://www.abc/Something">
    <ns0:Header>
    <ns0:Snumber>161003</ns0:Snumber>
    </ns0:Header>
    <ns0:Name>SomeEvent</ns0:Name>
    <ns0:NameSpace>http://www.abc/Something.xsd</ns0:NameSpace>
    <ns0:Id>3</ns0:Id>
     <ExtId>TEST_ID_12</ExtId>
     <CVersion>0</CVersion>
    </ns0:EMessage>
```

Have tried my best.Hope SO helps now.Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you show your code that creates the "<ns0:eventProperty>" nodes ?

Comment: @syllabusIt is not creating that node.Actually am reading the raw XML and i have remove the child to eventProperty node.But as eventProperty is a parent am not able to remove it and it resides in the output XML too.And it is opposite to what i want.That eventProperty element should not be there in output xml and the childs should become the child of roots.
Thanks

Comment: anyway, show your code for that

Comment: @syllabus:Its is just getting the text and creating a new element.Basically if you want to provide the solution take as ROOT and Parent P1 and Child C1 and C2.Remove the P1 tag and make C1 and C2 as immideate child.Why i am not posting code is it will look clumsy here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's strange to asnwer my own question.But finally i got the logic and answer for this.

Inspite of adding the elements to the `<ns0:eventProperty>` parent,should add the newly created element directly to the root which is `<ns0:EMessage>`.

**NOTE**::This whole process will be done in one loop.Use the Current Parent and using the data create immideate child to root by doing `root.appendChild(newChildElement)` and then in the same loop which will be running for all the child elements put the removing current parent logic in END.So that once your new elements got created just remove off the current parent.